# How am I supposed to react if ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem() returns FALSE?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()`. From MSDN I see that it can return FALSE if queuing failed. How am I supposed to react then? Wait a bit and try to queue again, hoping that a thread from th pool will be available then?

Comment: As I understand it it doesn't return false when queueing failed. It throws NotSupportedException.

Comment: +1 Good question. MSDN states `true if the method is successfully queued; NotSupportedException is thrown if the work item could not be queued`. Which makes me wonder when `false` is returned.

Comment: How I understand it: It is throwing the NotSupportedException if the concept of thread pooling is not supported on the platform. However, if it is supported but the thread cannot be queued, it will return false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's game over. Tell your user what happened and terminate your app.

Answer (score 2):

It is unlikely to return false (See here: [When ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150645/when-threadpool-queueuserworkitem-returns-false)). If it does - treat it as a failure and do not keep retrying.

Normally you would get a `NotSupportedException`.