# Multithreading Where to Start?

Tags: .net, multithreading

ive been doing some research on multithreading, and see there are loads of different ways of doing it.

thread,task,threadpool,etc etc

im using .net4 and making a simple windows application that basically has a method that interacts with a webpage. All i need to do is very basic:

- on click, run method A, X amount of times concurrently (X is to be specified
  by me and may vary).

Im so confused as to which method of multitaksing i should research into further to achieve this, i dont want to start learning lots of different ways that wont work for my needs just yet!

Apologies if this is not in the spirit of SO, i really want to dive in and get my hands dirty multithreading i just dont even know where to start! Thanks

Comment: This is too broad a question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: You might want to wait till you have a problem that requires it.

Comment: If you want a good book on multithreading and all it's facets, then you should buy Joe Duffy's [Concurrent Programming on Windows](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/books/winconc/winconc_book_resources.html).

Comment: There's an excellent ( and free ) beginners' ebook here: [Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your using .NET 4, a good place to start would be the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). The `ThreadPool` and the TPL are practically the same but the TPL makes it easier to do things like exception handling/cancellations etc.

I would avoid creating dedicated threads unless you *really* have to.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with James, if you want something as simple as possible and fast results (in terms of development time) I would create as many Threads (instance the `System.Thread` class and set the method to execute) as needed and execute the requested method.

It's the quick & dirty solution that will require less development effort.

Otherwise, if you want things done the right way, then TPL is the way to go, rigth, but somehow I got a feeling from your question that you were trying to get something simple done fast.

Comment: This is terrible advice. For someone who is looking learn multithreading (which for even experts can be tricky) telling them to jump in at the deep end isn't the way to go. Regardless, it's *much* easier to spawn a task/thread via the ThreadPool/TPL than it is to manage dedicated threads.

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not agree. Thread t = new Thread(MethodToCall); t.Start(); Nothing is easier than that. And to me looks like he's searching the solution to a problem, not trying to learn the whole multithreading model.

Comment: Task.Factory.StartNew(...) or ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(...) is just as easy to write, without the extra overhead of creating a new thread! Obviously it would be up to the OP to be more specific about what sort of jobs he intends the threads to be doing. However, I would *always* recommend utilising the .NET ThreadPool before creating new threads.

Comment: With ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(...) you have to check if the work item has been succesfully queued or not and retry on fail (if the threadpool runs out of free threads the call will return false), not sure about how the TPL works.

Comment: "*you have to check if the work item has been successfully queued or not and retry on fail*" - the likelihood of that happening is slim to none, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150645/when-threadpool-queueuserworkitem-returns-false). "*if the threadpool runs out of free threads the call will return false*" - When you call `QueueUserWorkItem` the action is queued until a thread becomes available, so it **won't** fail if there are no free threads - that's the point of queueing...it will only fail if for some reason it *can't* queue the action.