# Do I need to use try catch or check the return value of ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, threadpool

[ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yd16hza(v=vs.110).aspx)

The documentation of the method above says the following about its return type:

> true if the method is successfully queued; NotSupportedException is thrown if the work item could not be queued.

Does that mean that the function never returns false? But throws instead? If so, then why have a return type at all? I would say, or return true/false whether the WorkItem has been queued, or be of type void and throw when the WorkItem couldn't be queued.

I know there is this [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150645/when-threadpool-queueuserworkitem-returns-false), but it really isn't much of definite answer in my opinion.

Comment: Here's the source code: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/threadpool.cs,c4540b859da63a4a Not sure why it is so convoluted. Seems to always return true.

Comment: @usr Thanks, just looking at it. What is this purpose of an empty try with only code in the finally block?

Comment: Prevents ThreadAbortExceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read the docs  carefully. While MSDN states:

> true if the method is successfully queued; NotSupportedException is
>   thrown if the work item could not be queued.

...just bellow also states:

> NotSupportedException: The common language runtime (CLR) is hosted,
>   and the host does not support this action.

I mean, `NotSupportedException` will be thrown if the hosting environment doesn't support thread pooling.

Thus, if you're queueing threads where *you can do so*, you don't need a `try/catch` block. At least, you can check that the thread could be queued using the regular boolean return value.

Comment: Great! Didn't understand what that line ment and was confused of the return type explanation. Anyway, this is a better answer than any of the given answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150645/when-threadpool-queueuserworkitem-returns-false and it is in line with: only throw exceptions if you need to make sure that the calling code can't go around a failure, use returns values otherwise.

Comment: @MikedeKlerk No problem. BTW, it doesn't throw an exception when you think that it does. It does when the runtime environment doesn't support thread pooling... I'm not sure which one doesn't support it, maybe the .net microframework or who knows. I encourage you to avoid the try/catch as it won't never throw an exception in your scenario

Answer (score 1):

> Does that mean that the function never returns false? But throws
>   instead? If so, then why have a return type at all

[Lets look at the source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/threadpool.cs,c4540b859da63a4a,):

```
//ThreadPool has per-appdomain managed queue of work-items. The VM is
//responsible for just scheduling threads into appdomains. After that
//work-items are dispatched from the managed queue.
[System.Security.SecurityCritical]  // auto-generated
private static bool QueueUserWorkItemHelper(
    WaitCallback callBack, Object state, ref StackCrawlMark stackMark, bool compressStack)
{
    bool success =  true;

    if (callBack != null)
    {
        //The thread pool maintains a per-appdomain managed work queue.
        //New thread pool entries are added in the managed queue.
        //The VM is responsible for the actual growing/shrinking of 
        //threads. 

        EnsureVMInitialized();

        // If we are able to create the workitem, 
        // we need to get it in the queue without being interrupted
        // by a ThreadAbortException.
        //
        try { }
        finally
        {
            QueueUserWorkItemCallback tpcallBack = new QueueUserWorkItemCallback(
                                        callBack, state, compressStack, ref stackMark);
            ThreadPoolGlobals.workQueue.Enqueue(tpcallBack, true);
            success = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("WaitCallback");
    }
    return success;
}
```

It seems that success will truly either return `true`, as it is initially set before queuing the item, or throw an exception in case the runtime is unable to queue the delegate.

> Any better ideas?

That seems redundant to me, unless you don't really trust the run-time environment and not sure if it supplies an underlying thread-pooling mechanism. Otherwise if you're using Microsoft's run-time, you should be good simply using the original `QueueUserWorkItem`.